# Resize Html table to fit screen RSHINY

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

How can I resize the HTML table to fit the screen of the computer? This is how my shiny app looks currently[image: Interface of shiny app right now], I have tried using fluid row columns but it not giving me the right result. I guess I am missing something here.

Here is my shiny server and ui

UI.R

```
library("shiny")
library(daff)
library(dplyr)
library(shinythemes)
setwd("PATH")
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Automated Data Dictionary Comparison"),
    sidebarLayout(

      sidebarPanel(

        selectInput(inputId = 'Dic1',
                    label = 'Choose First Data Dictionary:',

                    choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                         full.names = FALSE,
                                         recursive = FALSE)),
        selectInput(inputId = 'Dic2',
                    label = 'Choose Second Data Dictionary:',
                    choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                         full.names = FALSE,
                                         recursive = FALSE))
      ),

      mainPanel(
         uiOutput('contents'))

    )
  )
)
```

Html table is in the output section.
SERVER.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(daff)
library(shinythemes)
setwd("PATH")
server <-  function(input, output) {
   # Parse first file
   dataset1 <- reactive({

      infile <- input$Dic1

      if (is.null(infile)){
         return(NULL)
      }
      x <- read.csv(paste0("./data/", infile[[1]]))
      x
   })
   # Parse second file
   dataset2 <- reactive({
      infile <- input$Dic2

      if (is.null(infile)){
         return(NULL)
      }
      x <- read.csv(paste0("./data/", infile[[1]]))
      x
   })
   # Create comparison table (reactive as both of its elements are reactive)
   diff <- reactive({
      x <- render_diff(diff_data(data_ref=dataset1(), data=dataset2()),use.DataTables=TRUE)
      x
   })
   #Output
   output$contents <- renderUI({
      HTML(diff())

   })
}
```

The expected result is my table to be fully seen on screen not extended that I have to scroll to see whole of it outside screen

Comment: `mainPanel` and `sidebarPanel` have arguments `width`. Try adjusting those.

Comment: @Roman Lustrik I have tried that but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try use this

```
                mainPanel(

                  HTML("<div style ='overflow:auto;  ' >"),
                  uiOutput('contents'),
                  HTML("</div>")

                )
```

or try set the `height` or set the `width` with css

```
                mainPanel(

                  HTML("<div style ='overflow:auto; height:500px ' >"),
                  uiOutput('contents'),
                  HTML("</div>")

                )
```

Comment: Is there a way I automate it that I don't have to struggle with manually changing sizes